# Setting WebAPI routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

In `WebApiConfig` I've added to routes :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "v1_Api",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "v1_ApiAction",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In ApiController I have 2 `GET` Actions :

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<RequestModel>> Pending(){}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<RequestModel>> Resolved()
```

When I tried to call one of this action from AngularJS service I got 500 Error.

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

When I left only second route, that match my Action - it works well.

```
"/api/v1/RequestRecipient/Pending"
```

In what can be problem in case of 2 routes?

Comment: what type do you expect for `id`. You may need to add a constraint because as it stands the path you showed will match both templates as id is optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found solution - Just need to change order of routes.

**From :**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "v1_Api",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "v1_ApiAction",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**To :**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "v1_ApiAction",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "v1_Api",
      routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But also I've found someone opinion, that this isn't good idea to have Action and Non-Action routes.